# Java Bit Operation on Long - Removing some bits

Tags: java

I have a long number. Now, what I want to do is the following:

```
long l = "001000......10001100000" (bits representation)
```

I need to remove the 3<sup>rd</sup> and 4<sup>th</sup> bits of it (*i.e.* 10) from the left and convert the remaining 62 bits to long

```
long newl = "0000......10001100000" (bits representation)
```

Can anybody help me do this efficiently in Java ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You typically *set* bits by `OR`ing them with a mask; you *clear* bits by `AND`ing them with the complement of a mask:

```
long mask = 3L << 60; // 001100...
long newl = l & ~mask;     // Clear the bits in the mask.
```

If you're looking to remove the bits (and effectively shorten the value to 62 bits), then you can try this:

```
long topBits = ((3L << 62) & l) >> 2; // Top 2 bits, shifted right
long bottomBits = (~(15L << 60) & l); // Bottom 60 bits
long newl = topBits | bottomBits;
```

Comment: Makes the two bits 0, but does not remove them.

Comment: @JoopEggen I didn't realize _remove_ actually meant _remove_; I thought it meant _clear_.  :-)  Updated to actually remove the bits.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the list of bits as a string, then simply remove the 3rd and 4th bits from that string and then use `Long.parseLong(string, 2)`.

Comment: Thus `long newl = Long.parseLong(string.substring(0, 2) + string.substring(4), 2)-,`